# Drawing Route Between infinite Places on GMSMapView in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I have 20 latitudes and 20 longitudes in different arrays. So I want to draw route using those points. can any one suggest me how to draw route from A to B & B to C & C to D.....

Comment: A to B & B to C & C to D.....is like A to D through B & C ! ?

Comment: http://www.meonbinary.com/2014/02/route-directions-with-ios7-mapkit-and-google-maps-api Take a look at this. This might help you.

Comment: they are using apple map but my requirement is i want to plot location (markups and line) on google map.

Comment: Did you read Google Maps iOS documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_polyline

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Directions API for your coordinate pairs, it will return, among other things, a polyline string that you can use to create GMSPath (use +pathFromEncodedPath:) which in turn you can use to create a GMSPolyline (use +polylineWithPath:) on your map.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to draw polylines among list of markers.
annotations- NSMutableArray containing GMSMarker Objects.

```
- (void)drawLineSubroutine
      {
        GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    for (int i=0; i<annotations.count; i++)
    {
        GMSMarker *marker = [annotations objectAtIndex:i];
        [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(marker.position.latitude,marker.position.longitude)];

    }

    polyLine = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    polyLine.strokeWidth = 1.0f;
    polyLine.map = mapGoogle;

}
```